# Why do hotel rooms often have no central light?

Tags: usa, hotels

When I stay at ordinary hotels in the United States it seems there is rarely or never any central light. The entryway usually has an overhead light, but the room itself usually just has lamps, so to light up the room I have to go around turning on lamps (in the dark). By contrast, in private homes usually each room has a central light and there is a switch by the door, so as you enter you can flip the switch and the room lights up. Why do hotels use lamps and have no central overhead light?

Comment: It has to do with a combination of operational efficiency, theft detection, energy consumption, visual impact, and guest satisfaction. It's discussed occasionally in trade magazines targeted at hotel management.

Comment: **Construction cost.**  In America there must be a switch, but it's legal to elide the overhead light in favor of a switched receptacle. You're supposed to leave that lamp switched on at the lamp.  This saves a fortune in construction costs. Even moreso in hotels, due to their commercial construction methods.  IMO the rest is rationalization.  I think it's crazy and criminal, first responders have the same problem you have!